# Rust/Actix current traceId/spanId when out of scope

Tags: logging, rust, trace, actix-web, distributed-tracing

I'm pretty new to Actix/Rust (coming from Java+SpringBoot).

I am setting up a Rust microservice and need to integrate it into the rest of the tracing ecosystem at my company. We are using [ECS](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/ecs-logging/overview/current/intro.html) format for our logs so that we can easily see all of the logs for a given request by filtering on the `traceId`

My goal is to include a traceId into a structured log event  when something is logged from the log crate (`info!()` / `warn!()` / `error!()`). I would like to get this traceId from B3 propagation headers.

For example, I would like for the following code to create 3 log events that all have the traceId.

```rs
#[get("/")]
pub async fn hello() -> impl Responder {
    info!("1");
    info!("2");
    info!("3");
    HttpResponse::Ok().body("Hello world!")
}
```

I am using env_logger with a custom pipe to send the logs

```rs
env_logger::builder()
        .format(ecs_logger::format) // Configure ECS logger
        .target(env_logger::Target::Pipe(Box::new(kafka_pipe))) // Write to Kafka
        .init();
```

However, my issue is that I am struggling find a way to get the current traceId/spanId into the log record. In Java, the MDC class is how I would accomplish

```java
// Middleware filter in SpringBoot
MDC.put("traceId", "<my-trace-id>");
```

I've tried using various crates like tracing/opentelemetry but I am getting a bit overwhelmed by all of the crates and how they interact with each other.

Comment: Take a look at the [`tracing`](https://crates.io/crates/tracing) crate: it allows you to define spans and attach metadata to them.

Comment: yes, however my question is more along the lines of how do all of the tracing packages in the Rust ecosystem fit together? I'm a little lost on the difference between the tracing and opentelemetry packages.

Comment: `log` is just a facade. It defines the `debug!`, `info!`, etc. macros, but by themselves they do nothing. It requires a backend that defines how to handle them. `tracing` is another facade which offers more functionality (notably spans), but it too requires a backend to actually trace the messages.

Comment: [`tracing-log`](https://crates.io/crates/tracing-log) is a `log` backend that forwards to `tracing` so that they can be used together. [`opentelemetry`](https://crates.io/crates/opentelemetry) provides backends [for `log`](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-rust/blob/main/opentelemetry-appender-log/README.md) or [for `tracing`](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-rust/blob/main/opentelemetry-appender-tracing/README.md) that enable them to send their traces to an Open Telemetry server.

Comment: I see, that is very helpful. I did not realize that `tracing` is also just a facade.